# How to save working hours of multiple stores and then query it without duplication?

Tags: mysql, order-by

I'm want to create database with stores. Each store has their own working hours in a week. Then I want to query the store and sort them by nearest store which is currently open. So far I create this schema but unfortunatly I cannot query it like I would like to. The schema looks like this

[image]

This is the query I'm using currently (for day: Saturday and hour: 3:15 PM):

```
SELECT so.day, so.store_id, so.open, so.close 
FROM shop_openings so 
ORDER BY FIELD(so.day, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ASC, 
         '15:15' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci 
                 NOT BETWEEN CONCAT( LPAD( so.open, 2, '0'), ':00') 
                         AND CONCAT( LPAD( so.close, 2, '0'), ':00'), 
         LPAD( so.close, 2, '0' ), 
         LPAD( so.open, 2, '0' )
```

But it query just like the screen above shows.

Now here's what the list I want to achieve:

Let we say that today is Saturday. We have 4 stores which only 2 of them works in Saturday. I want to recieve 4 results order by day and open/close hours. Below I selected which rows I want to get:

[image]

No other results. Only 4 results as we have 4 stores in `store_table`. Nearest 2 shops opened in Saturday and then 2 shops opened in Monday.

I have no idea how the schema should like other than mine, so any suggestion are welcome.

Here is a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9709e/1/0

Comment: Does your MySQL version  is really 5.6?

Comment: > 5.6 but this version in on fiddle

Comment: *From query in that fiddle I want only first 4 results* The data (even fieldnames!) in a fidle does not match to ones on the screenshots. Edit either your fiddle or your question (especially desired output) please. And specily your REAL server version.

Comment: @Akina I update a fiddle and my MySQL version is: 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu)) (I dont know how to check the version in fiddle, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the next day, and sundays are closed you can use this query,, when you want the next two days You have to UNION another Query and exclude all previous shops like i did in the WHERE clause

You can replace the @searchday session  variable with DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) to get the actual 
day

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `shop_openings` (
>   `shop_id` int,
>   `day` int,
>   `open` varchar(5),
>   `close` varchar(5)
>   );
>
>   INSERT INTO `shop_openings` VALUES
>   (10, 6, '9:00', '16:00'),
>   (10, 5, '9:00', '16:00'),
>   (10, 4, '9:00', '16:00'),
>   (10, 3, '9:00', '16:00'),
>   (10, 2, '9:00', '16:00'),
>   (10, 1, '9:00', '16:00'),
>   (11, 6, '10:00', '18:00'),
>   (11, 4, '10:00', '18:00'),
>   (11, 2, '9:00', '18:00'),
>   (12, 5, '9:00', '17:00'),
>   (12, 3, '9:00', '17:00'),
>   (12, 1, '9:00', '17:00'),
>   (13, 4, '9:00', '16:00'),
>   (13, 3, '9:00', '16:00');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SET @searchday = 6;
> SELECT so.day, so.shop_id, so.open, so.close 
> FROM shop_openings so 
> WHERE `day` = @searchday
> UNIOn
> SELECT so.day, so.shop_id, so.open, so.close 
> FROM shop_openings so 
> WHERE `day` = IF(@searchday = 7 Or @searchday = 6,1,@searchday + 1)
> AND shop_id NOT IN(SELECT so.shop_id 
> FROM shop_openings so 
> WHERE `day` = @searchday)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> day | shop_id | open  | close
> --: | ------: | :---- | :----
>   6 |      10 | 9:00  | 16:00
>   6 |      11 | 10:00 | 18:00
>   1 |      12 | 9:00  | 17:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=94c8ad24cc5b6934be9ef98d61fda487)*

Comment: It's looking good but I want to see all next days until todays (if today is saturday then i want to see Sat-Fri, Sundays also), so I should make 6 UNION queries? Is it good for performance?

Comment: You can make a stored procedure out of it, if you want all very flexible, where you select a day and also how many days to search.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like correct way I think but I need to implement this query to existing system and I can just extend existing query

Comment: could you give an example how to create a procedure with this solution as you said in previous comment?

Comment: You create a temporary table for your resultset. You  have a loop over 7 days, You start from the day wanted for example Saturday And take my Select from above but you insert it directly into the temporary table and exclude all ids that are already in the temporary table. After 7 days you have all the shops in the order of days since startday.

Answer (score 0):

Given input of @day=6 for Saturday, replace

```
ORDER BY FIELD(so.day, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ASC
```

by

```
ORDER BY 
    IF(`day` < @day, `day` + 7, `day`),   -- wrap the days (Mon = 8, etc)
```

and tack this on the end:

```
LIMIT 4
```

You might want to LPAD the incoming time.